# Как узнать, в какой строке создается поток в android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть проект, который очень плохо написан, и в нем использовано много reflection... много ошибок.

Мне нужно найти, что где находится. Например, в ситуации, когда у меня есть две точки останова, но прежде чем я дойду до второй, открывается множество тредов. Я подумал, что могу использовать окно потоков в андроид студио, чтобы найти места, где создаются эти потоки, и таким образом найти точки останова, чтобы использовать их позже во время отладки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Comment: Дебаггер не поможет найти где потоки создаются и запускаются - только где начинается их выполнение: `run()` и по цепочке вверх, пока не попадёте в код приложения, всё что ниже вам вряд ли будет полезным. Собственно туда и нужно ставить точки останова, чтобы остановить этот поток. Если нужно выяснить откуда и зачем поток запустили - ищите по исходникам упоминание классов указанных в стеке потока.